# How can I get the average of three differing values in multiple lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a file that contains data for each second in a 5 minute period. It contains a timestamp, the temperature, the humidity, and the pressure at the given time. I've been able to open the file and turn each set of data into its own separate list. This prints many different lists that all look similar but have slightly different values. An example of a line that it outputs looks like

```
['2019-10-07 14:37:13', '22.3', '48.9', '987.9']
```

The 22.3 in this list is the temperature, the 48.9 is the humidity, and the 987.9 is the pressure. I need to print the resulting list.

```
def process_file():
infile = open('data.csv', 'r')
for x in infile:
    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    line_contents = line.split(",")
    infile.close
    print(line_contents)
```

Comment: Can you please give some more details. Question is not clear.

Comment: What do u wanna do with the resulting list? Be more specific.

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your post (rolled back).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the current code is correct, you can do something like that

```py
def process_file():
    infile = open('5min.csv', 'r')
    humidity_sum = 0
    temperature_sum = 0
    pressure_sum = 0
    for x in infile:
        line = infile.readline()
        line = line.strip()
        line_contents = line.split(",")
        humidity_sum += float(line_contents[1])
        temperature_sum += float(line_contents[2])
        pressure_sum += float(line_contents[3])
        infile.close
    humidity_mean = humidity_sum / len(infile)
    temperature_mean = temperatur_sum / len(infile)
    pressure_mean = pressure_sum / len(infile)
    print(humidity_mean, temperature_mean, pressure_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
def process_file():
    infile = open('5min.csv', 'r')
    temp=0;hum=0;pres=0
    count=0
    line = infile.readline()    #do it since the first line is label as per you
    for x in infile:
        count+=1
        line = infile.readline()
        line = line.strip()
        line_contents = line.split(",")
        temp+=float(line_contents[1])
        hum+= float(line_contents[2])
        pres+=float(line_contents[3])        
    infile.close
    print([temp/count,hum/count,pres/count])
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. When I try to run this it gives an error from line 8: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I am unable to find the error. Try using this `for i in range(l):`

Comment: I didn't realize it until this morning, but the first line of my csv folder is a line of labels that doesn't store any values. Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, it must be the problem. Copy the first line after the for loop statement and paste it  just above the same statement and decrease the value of l by 1. It should work.

Comment: Now it's saying that infile has no len()

Comment: Then use a counter varible for the division. I am editing my solution to so it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means

Comment: I mean a counter variable like i just used `count`  whose values increases on each execution of the loop. Check the edited  code i just submit.